# UIPickerView data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a uipickerview which is used to displays names in a uitextfield, any ideas on how I would pass a value that is hidden from the user into a variable. Can I somehow associate the value with the name in the NSArray while not displaying it.
Thank you

Trying a dictionary but am stuck on something that is probably pretty simple, I have a dictionary

```
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3", @"4", nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

and in didSelectRow I have

```
    NSString *itemKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", row];
    survonemd.text = [dictionary objectForKey:itemKey];
```

which seems ok

but am stuck on titleForRow

any help or tips would be much appreciated.

I now have -

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *keys;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *objects;


@synthesize keys;
@synthesize objects;


self.keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
self.objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"5", @"6", nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSString *itemKey = [keys objectAtIndex:row];
return [dictionary objectForKey:itemKey]; 
}

- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSString *itemKey = [keys objectAtIndex:row];
survonemd.text = [dictionary objectForKey:itemKey]; 
}
```

It runs and the picker view gets called from the textfield but no data is displayed in the picker. Please help.

Comment: Providing some code might help, but I would recommend using NSDictionary since it allows you to have keys and values. You could make the keys displayed on the UIPickerView, each corresponding to a value hidden to the user.

Comment: Thanks Jumhyn, I am trying to use a dictionary but am stuck on something that should be pretty simple. I have a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating the key string from the row number (for which you would use `%i` instead of `%f` by the way), use the row as the index into the keys array:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *itemKey = [keys objectAtIndex:row];
    survonemd.text = [dictionary objectForKey:itemKey]; 
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *itemKey = [keys objectAtIndex:row];
    return [dictionary objectForKey:itemKey];   
}
```

This way, the key values also don't have to be numbers-as-strings.

Define your keys and dictionary objects as properties and set them using `self.keys = ...` so you can access them properly.

Comment: @Mattog1456: Looking at the updated code in your question, I think you'll also need to make dictionary a property and set it using self.dictionary.  To verify dictionary has the data, in titleForRow, before the return, add `NSLog(@"dict=%@", dictionary);`.  Does it show the dictionary data?

Comment: Thank you very much aBitObvious I set the dictionary with self. and it  is working, cheers.

Comment: Great.  I should have explained: by declaring as properties, some of the memory management was taken care of for you and made sure that the data you assigned to the var gets retained for later use.  See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) in the docs for more details.  Also, you should release those properties in dealloc to avoid a memory leak (eg. `[keys release];`, etc).